# Magento 1.9 Custom Category Attribute exists in EAV_Attribute but not showing in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

I have been trying to add a custom category attribute to our Magento 1.9.4.2 site using this tutorial:

https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

The module installs and successfully adds the new attribute to the eav_attribute table however I cannot get it to show on the edit categories page.

Ive logged in and out, flushed the cache and reindexed many times now, also truncated all the flat category tables and reindexed again after that but it just wont show up.

The module appears in the core_resource_table so it looks like the module is doing what it should but for some reason its not showing the new attribute for editing.

I used the same tutorial a couple of years ago for one of our other sites and it all seemed to work perfectly. I tried copying the exact entries out of the other sites database into the new one but again this seemed to do nothing.

Is there any differences in the way Magento 1.9.4.2 handles attributes in the eav_attribute table compared to previous Magento versions.

Here are the entries in my eav_attribute table:

```
entity_type_id: 3
attribute_code: top_description
attribute_model: NULL
backend_model: NULL
backend_type: text
backend_table: NULL
frontend_model: NULL
frontend_input: textarea
frontend_label: Top Description
frontend_class: NULL
source_model:
is_required: 0 
is_user_defined: 0
default_value:
is_unique: 0
note:
```

Can anyone see any problems with those entries or have any idea why its not showing?

Thanks

Comment: is that a typo in frontend_class? (miising letter t).... also frontend_lable should be frontend_label but again that just may be your typo

Comment: yes, sorry thats just my typos, was awkward to copy from phpmyadmin